# Get individual result from function

Tags: swift

This will most likely be really easy for those who know :)

I'm using the following.

```
fpingx.ping(hosts: ["google.com"], progress: { (progress) in
            print(progress)
        }) { (result) in
            print(result)
```

And basically just want to get what is outputted into a label. The output shown from the print is:

> google.com : xmt/rcv/%loss = 1/1/0%, min/avg/max = 2.45/2.45/2.45

I'm fairly new to this and searched all I could think of.

The dev says the following, which may help someone help me

The result is a dictionary which key is host string, value is FpingxResult.

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Docs on [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/pods/fpingx) (just under your quoted line) state:

> Notice that FpingxResult is a struct defined as:

```
public struct FpingxResult {

    public let host: String

    /// number of sent
    public let xmt: Int

    /// number of received
    public let rcv: Int

    /// loss percentage (value from 0-100)
    public var loss: Int {
        return xmt > 0 ? (xmt - rcv) * 100 / xmt : 0
    }

    /// nil if rcv is 0
    public let avg: Int?

    /// nil if rcv is 0
    public let min: Int?

    /// nil if rcv is 0
    public let max: Int?

}
```

Because the result is a [dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary) you would need to access the value for the host name first by accessing the key for the domain.

```
let googleResult = result["google.com"] // this gives you a single `FpingxResult`
averageLabel.text = "\(googleResult?.avg ?? 0)"
```

Comment: Thank you sir, not sure how I overlooked that!